# Evaluating a multivariable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

No matter which way I approach this, I get 0. But how can I rearrange this equation into something that is defined?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but note that $$\left\vert\dfrac{3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right\vert \leq \left\vert \dfrac{3xy^2}{y^2}\right\vert, \text{for all }(x,y)\neq (0,0).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: put polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos\theta\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;(x,y)\to (0,0)\iff r\to 0, \text{and our limit is:}$$

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{3r^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}3r\cos\theta\sin^2\theta=0$$

Comment: This polar coordinate method is interesting. Does it only work for $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Comment: Not at all, but in other cases it may harder to apply it.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $$\left|3y\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right| = 3|y|\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2} \le 3|y|\frac{|xy|}{2|x||y|} = \frac{3|y|}2.$$